# Selecting multiple rows in GridView with checkboxes: Program not pulling data

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I have been coming across a strange bug/error in my code when attempting to select and pull data from multiple rows in GridView controls.

**Background:**
In short, I have a GridView item, populated with rows of different equipment items that are "checked in" and available to check out of our system. I want to have the user able to select multiple items and check them out at once, rather than doing it X times.

I am using a check box item on each row to do this, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slDk6.png

There is a button at the bottom to check the equipment out of our database.

**Code:**
The code I am using to generate the ASPX page is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEquipment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table table-bordered">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMultiSelect_Out" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Equipment Name" DataField="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="Category.Name" />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There is no equipment to display.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
<div class="well">
    <asp:Button ID="btnCheckOut" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-inverse" Text="Check Out" OnClick="btnCheckOut_Click" />
</div>
```

This works and compiles with no problem.

The code running the button to check everything out is:

```
protected void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int checkoutNumber = 0;
        //string id = (sender as Button).Attributes["data-id"].ToString();

        SortedBindingList<Tracker.Business.Equipment> eqList = Tracker.Business.EquipmentList.FetchAll();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.grdEquipment.Rows)
        {
                CheckBox chkMultiSelect_Out = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkMultiSelect_Out") ;
                if (chkMultiSelect_Out.Checked)
                {
                    checkoutNumber++;
                    Tracker.Business.Equipment equip = Tracker.Business.Equipment.GetByIdentification(Int32.Parse(row.ID.ToString()));
                    eqList.Add(equip);
                }

        }

        //If checkoutNumber is 0, do nothing.
        //If checkoutNumber is 1, launch popup for only 1 item
        //If checkoutNumber is more than 1, launch popup for multiple items.
        if (checkoutNumber == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Equipment/CheckInOut/Default.aspx");
        }
        else if (checkoutNumber == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (checkoutNumber > 1)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now, OBVIOUSLY, this code isn't finished. I am debugging as I go to make my life easier.
The important code is the foreach loop where I check each row for the control item, and see if it is checked or not.

**The Problem:**
When I run the code, and test with some check boxes checked, it looks at all the rows, and ALL of them have "Checked = false" as an attribute. What's worse, I found out later that it doesn't even grab the data from the row, as shown in this screen shot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGwli.png

The text should be "Optimus Prime" or "Switch #1", however it is not! And both are checked when I run the code, yet the code sees only false checked items.

The code runs through the foreach loop for each row, i.e., 3 rows, it runs through the loop 3 times. So it sees each row, yet it is not pulling the data...

Where should I start looking?

Comment: Where do you set the text since it's not set declaratively on the aspx markup? Are you databinding the `GridView` also on postbacks? If you databind it manually and you should do it only `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: I would second Tim's comment. There's a good chance your grid is being re-databound before the OnClick event fires, resulting in all of your changes being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. As [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) said, I was postbacking the page on every click, so I changed my code to databind the gridview table only on a page load, and not on a post back. Works now!